# Upload new firmware using IAR C-SPY command line tool

Tags: embedded, iar

I'm trying to upload new firmware via I-Jet to my ARM Cortex-M4 MCU using IAR command line tool C-SPY. Here's what I type in the command line:

```
cmd:> "PROJECT_FOLDER\iar\settings\wrk_gt21.cspy.bat" "PROJECT_FOLDER\iar\wrk_gt21\flash debug\exe\project.out"
```

This is the response I receive:

```
"IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\common\bin\cspybat" 
"IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\arm\bin\armproc.dll" 
"IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\arm\bin\armJET.dll"  
"PROJECT_FOLDER\iar\wrk_gt21\flash debug\exe\project.out" 
--plugin "IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\arm\bin\armbat.dll" 
--macro "IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\arm\config\debugger\Freescale\Trace_Kxx.dmac" 
--flash_loader "IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\arm\config\flashloader\Freescale\FlashK60Fxxx128K.board" 
--backend -B "--endian=little" "--cpu=Cortex-M4" "--fpu=VFPv4" "-p" 
"IAR_INSTALLATION_PATH\arm\CONFIG\debugger\Freescale\MK20FX512xxx12.ddf" 
"--semihosting=none" 
"--device=MK20FX512xxx12"  
"--jet_standard_reset=1,0,0" 
"--jet_jtag_speed=12000" 
"--drv_catch_exceptions=0x000"

     IAR C-SPY Command Line Utility V6.4.7.0
     Copyright 2000-2012 IAR Systems AB.

----- Prepare hardware for Flashloader -----

WARNING: Skipping flash loading pass because there is no data in the designated range: 0x10000000-0x13FFFFFF.
ERROR: Failed to load debugee: PROJECT_FOLDER\iar\wrk_gt21\flash debug\exe\project.out
Failed to load debug file: PROJECT_FOLDER\iar\wrk_gt21\flash debug\exe\project.out
```

I can successfully upload new firmware through IAR GUI (by clicking "Download and Debug"), but command line tool doesn't seem to work. Googling and reading documentation on C-SPY didn't give me any new information on this problem.

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the debug file as a test. I'm never 100% on working directories, but the batch file may be working from the `settings` directory, and so your relative path won't be correct.

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it didn't help. Also I tried to move the debug file to another folder, which doesn't have spaces in its name, but this didn't help either.

Comment: I'm at a loss. I'd contact IAR for assistance. The warning seems to indicate that it opened the file correctly and found data in the flash range starting at `0x00000000` and not in the range starting at `0x10000000`, which I would expect for most applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try to contact IAR support and post solution for this issue here if I'll get any.